# Terracotta timeToIdleSeconds verse timeToLiveSeconds

Tags: caching, ehcache, terracotta

All,

Here's my understanding of the two elements, I wanted to clarify.

timeToIdleSeconds = An object will be evicted if it's idle for more than X seconds.

From documentation

> If a client accesses an element in myCache that has been idle for more
>   than an hour (timeToIdleSeconds), it evicts that element. The element
>   is also evicted from the Terracotta Server Array.

If the object in cache is not requested again, will it ever get evicted?  Will the cache sizing constraints be the only way to clean up this cached object that's not requested again?

timeToLiveSeconds = An object will be evicted if it's been cached for more than X seconds.  Does this work the same way as timeToIdleSeconds?  Only evicted when requested again?  Or will this get cleaned up by a background process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your final question: " Or will this get cleaned up by a background process?"

http://terracotta.org/apidocs/terracotta-toolkit/3.2.0/org/terracotta/cache/CacheConfig.html

in both setMaxTTISeconds and setMaxTTLSeconds has:

"The background eviction thread sleep interval is based on this value and the Max TTL, so a side effect of changing this value is to change the sleep interval of the eviction thread."

I'm assuming that the different versions of Terracotta will be similar; I believe that there will be a background thread doing cleanup.

If that's correct, then it would seem to imply that a request is not necessary to trigger an eviction, somewhat contrary to the documentation you quote.

Comment: Based on my tests, it seems that the TTL works that way.  The background thread (DGC) cleans up the old objects in cache based on the TTL.  The Time to Idle (TTI) doesn't seem to get cleaned up by that background process.  I see the caches fill up and never go back down.  Objects are evicted to make room for new objects but the max cache size remains full.